# How to embed drupal content in other sites (remove X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN)?

Tags: 8

I tried to make a iframe with a drupal page but I received the following message:

> Multiple "Refused to display (page adress) in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

Then, I tried to change the header of response in page controller using

`$response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'GOFORIT');`

And I received the following message

> Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('GOFORIT, SAMEORIGIN') encountered when loading '(page adress)'. Falling back to 'DENY'.

Drupal core puts the following code in all responses.

`$response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN', FALSE);`

So, how can I override the X-Frame-Options header for only this response to embed this page in other sites?

I'm using Drupal 8.0.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `X-Frame-Options` header seems to have been added to Drupal 8 in order to prevent click-jacking: https://www.drupal.org/node/2514152

According to the notification above, in order to embed your Drupal site in other sites,

> a new Response Subscriber needs to be added that has a higher priority
>   as the current FinishResponseSubscriber (see core.services.yml) to
>   overwrite or remove the header - depending on the use case

It also provides a code example:

```
<?php
    $path = $request->getPathInfo();

    if (strpos($path, '/fb-app/') === 0) {
      $request->headers->remove('X-Frame-Options');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 30):

Drupal 8 adds the response header `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` to all pages. This prevents that the content is included in iframes on third party sites.

You can check this for example in the google image search that your content does not appear in the preview frame.

This feature was introduced in drupal 8 beta 13.

The change record

[Core is now protected against click-jacking by default (X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2514152)

is not correct in that the priority has to be higher, in fact it has to be lower. The code example changes the request but it has to change the response.

To provide a solution to the question here is the complete code including the yaml file to put this in the service container:

`mymodule/src/EventSubscriber/RemoveXFrameOptionsSubscriber.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class RemoveXFrameOptionsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public function removeXFrameOptions(ResponseEvent $event) {
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $response->headers->remove('X-Frame-Options');
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::RESPONSE][] = ['removeXFrameOptions', -10];
    return $events;
  }
}
```

`mymodule/mymodule.services.yml`:

```
services:
  remove_x_frame_options_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\RemoveXFrameOptionsSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Comment: I'm using a custom field formatter to include Youtube iframes. How do I remove these X-Frame-Options for displaying YouTube iframe Player?

Comment: This answer should be accepted now - it's well thought through and complete. Also thanks for the drop-in code, very helpful.

Comment: @4k4 life saver

Comment: Would suggest to use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ResponseEvent instead of FilterResponseEvent from D9

Answer (score 8):

4k4 give great solution, but also may be

> $response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://ALLOWED.SITE/');

better then

> $response->headers->remove('X-Frame-Options');

Comment: Note that `allow-from uri` is deprecated and will no longer work on modern browsers. The only 2 options this header has at the moment is `sameorigin` or `deny`. [X-Frame-Options MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: And also note that if you use it anyway to support IE (in addition to [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors), as suggested by drupov), since unlike `frame-ancestors` it only seems to accept a single domain, this would break things like "remote video" embeds, which Drupal media renders with an outer iframe that's `SAMEORIGIN`.

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple to override the headers from `.htaccess` with a single statement

```
Header set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "ALLOWALL"
```

**Alternativelly** you can make it only apply on certain condition using [if statement apache expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples)

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /embed/">
    Header set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "ALLOWALL"
</If>
```

and then you can call your URL adding `embed` in your query string

```
https://domain.com/yoururl?param1=true&embed
```

For this to work you will need **apache 2.4** or greater and **headers** module enabled.  If not enabled you perhaps you can enable them with

```
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 4):

There's now a downloadable module for Drupal 8: [X-Frame-Options Configuration](https://www.drupal.org/project/x_frame_options)

> This module can be used to set the x-frame-options header on your
>   website with the appropriate directive. This might be useful when you
>   want to include one of the pages of your site inside an iframe in
>   another site.
>
> The directives must be:
>
> 1. DENY
> 2. SAMEORIGIN
> 3. ALLOW-FROM uri (Currently [2018-10-25] not accepted by chrome nor Safari). You will be allowed to configure which uri.

Answer (score 2):

For newer browsers the `ALLOW-FROM uri`-settings would not work anymore, see "allow-from uri (obsolete)"-section in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

You need to add

`$response->headers->set('Content-Security-Policy', 'frame-ancestors https://ALLOWED.SITE/');` in addition to what wakh.ru proposed:

`$response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://ALLOWED.SITE/');`

Comment: Note that you if you use "Remote video" Media on your site (which render with an outer same-origin iframe), you'll also want to account for that in `Content-Security-Policy` (e.g. `frame-ancestors 'self' allowed.other.site` with quotes required for `'self'`) since setting CSP seems to disregard/overrule `X-Frame-Options` set elsewhere, whether by core as `SAMEORIGIN`, or by customization as `ALLOW-FROM` (and since `ALLOW-FROM` also only accepts a single value, setting it to `https://allowed.other.site` also seems to break the video embeds in IE).