# 8 - Alter HTTP Response Headers

Tags: theming, 8, http-request

I noticed [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188924/how-to-embed-drupal-content-in-other-sites-remove-x-frame-options-sameorigin/201297#201297), which discusses various ways to alter HTTP Response Headers.

Where would I be able to execute:

```
$response->headers->remove('X-Frame-Options');
```

I attempted to place this within my THEMENAME.theme file, but perhaps I am not doing it right because `$response` is not defined where I am using it.

Where does `$response` come from?

Where can I execute `$response->headers->remove('X-Frame-Options');`?

Note: I understand the risks of removing the HTTP Header.  This is for development/testing purposes only.

Comment: Sounds like it should be an EventSubscriber to me.

Comment: @Kevin, are custom modules required for EventSubscribers?

Comment: Yes. Check some of the docs and blogs about them.

Comment: @Kevin, can you clarify where a custom service should live relative to the root Drupal installation?  I've tried from the root level and also from `/modules`, and Drupal is not picking up my Event subscription.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

From these two sources:

- [How to embed drupal content in other sites (remove X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188924/how-to-embed-drupal-content-in-other-sites-remove-x-frame-options-sameorigin/201297#201297)
- https://wunderkraut.se/blogg/remove-xframe-options-and-set-contentsecuritypolicy

I realized that I was missing a `mymodule.info.yml` file.

```
mymodule 
  ├── mymodule.info.yml 
  ├── mymodule.services.yml 
  └── src 
    └── EventSubscriber 
      └── RemoveXFrameOptionsSubscriber.php
```

Then, go to `/admin/modules` in the backend (Extend tab) and install the new module & clear all caches afterwards.

Woohoo!