# Views Remember Last Selection Back Button D8

Tags: views, caching

I am having trouble with "Remember last selection" on views in D8. If I click a link away from the view and click back it does not remember my last selection. If I then refresh the page it does. This view does use Ajax and I cannot change that. Also I read somewhere that it may be due to caching from the headers.

If so what is the best way to add / change headers on a View response?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to subscribe to an event and manipulate the headers from there. I originally found this answer on how to manipulate headers in D8 [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188924/how-to-embed-drupal-content-in-other-sites-remove-x-frame-options-sameorigin/201297#201297).

This will force a request to the server:

This file will go into your mymodule/src/EventSubscriber folder.

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class NoCacheSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public function RemoveCacheHeaders(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::RESPONSE][] = array('RemoveCacheHeaders', -10);
    return $events;
  }
}
```

Then this will go into the your mymodule folder as mymodule.services.yml

```
    services:
  remove_cache_options_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\NoCacheSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Comment: this would completly disable cache browser cache, wouldnt it?

Comment: For that specific page yes

Comment: I think this will disable the cache for the whole site.

Comment: Oh yes you are correct it does. You could get the current route and determine it by that.