# Serve Anonymous Pages when users are logged in for some pages

Tags: caching, performance, proxies

so essentially I have a Drupal website with great performance for anonymous users and terrible performance for logged in users.

What I am looking for is a way to serve some pages that logged in users access as if they were an anonymous user.

In custom development this would be done using a:

```
cache-control:public
```

header for varnish, but obviously when viewing that page anything such as the users profile information and the login status must not be shown so its not cached in varnish.

I was hoping there would be a config change or module that could perform this without having to write a custom module,

any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have the internal caching modules enabled? Are you using additional cache mechanisms like memcache or redis?

Comment: Have you looked at the Big Pipe module for Drupal 8 (assuming that the site in question is Drupal 8)?

Comment: For a low level solution like the one you've mentioned in custom development you could add `$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'public');` in a [response subcriber](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188924/how-to-embed-drupal-content-in-other-sites-remove-x-frame-options-sameorigin/201297#201297) and in the same subscriber remove the user related content from `$response->getContent()`.

Comment: @Kevin I'm using authcache with memcached but the performance vs varnish is significantly slower. With varnish I can handle well over 2000 simultaneous users, with authcache and memcached I struggle with more than 100 users

Comment: @ScottJoudry sorry forgot to mention the site in question is drupal 7, but always interested in solutions for drupal 8 sites

Comment: @4k4 interestingly if I don't find a perfect solution I could create a small module that looks for cache-control header and if its public remove user related information, as setting the header itself is fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

You may implement ESI block caching.

Have a look at [ESI module](https://www.drupal.org/project/esi)  and [varnish basic tutorial](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/esi.html). You would be able then to cache whole pages except the blocks with session data.

Additionally, @Kevin comment points a complementary way: using **Redis** or **Memcache** will substantially speed the pages when logged, by *caching data and objects in server memory* to reduce the number of times the data source must be read.

Comment: Obviously this will be open to interpretation but how does this compare with authcache in terms of performance for logged in users? If it has superior performance I would be very interested in moving away from authcache.

Comment: I don't know, implement both and benchmark it ;). More seriously, there are several combinations of caching methods, I use Varnish for anon and redis for logged and it blazingly fasten websites, even with complex edit forms....