# Creating iframe to be used in other websites

Tags: 8, page-controller

I've created a controller with the route "/get-info", the controller return a template `custom-info.html.twig`

`my_module/src/Controller/MyController.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class MyController extends ControllerBase {

  public function content() {

    return [
      '#theme' => "custom_info",
    ];
  }
}
```

`my_module/templates/custom-info.html.twig` file:

```
<h1> Hello World </h1>
```

When visiting the path: www.mySite.com/get-info I get response with the header an footer of my site and "Hello World" as content. but when using `<iframe src="www.mySite.com/get-info"></iframe>` in an other Drupal project I get an empty iframe.

Is this the right way to create iFrame-ready Widgets in Drupal 8? if so what should I add/remove to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed drupal content in other sites (remove X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188924/how-to-embed-drupal-content-in-other-sites-remove-x-frame-options-sameorigin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing and enabling [Allow site iframing](https://www.drupal.org/project/allow_iframed_site) contrib module.

> Drupal 8 has a feature built into core that stops the site from being
>   rendered within an iframe, there are good reasons for this -
>   https://www.drupal.org/node/2514136 But sometimes you want your site
>   in an iframe, so that's what this module does.