# Cache-Control response header includes "private"

Tags: 8, caching

Why does a vanilla Drupal 8 site add `cache-control: must-revalidate, no-cache, private` to all the pages?

A Drupal 7 site adds `cache-control: must-revalidate, no-cache`.

Is that addition of `private` for Drupal 8 somehow configurable? I'd like to not have it there.

It turns out that this response header in Drupal 8 is sent when `system.performance:cache.page.max_age` is set to 0. Setting it to anything greater than 0 (e.g 123) gives me `max-age=123, public`. The question still remains: Is there a way to get `must-revalidate, no-cache`?

The reason I want `must-revalidate, no-cache` without `private` is that I want browsers to always make requests for pages, and my cache server (fastly) to cache the content. Having `private` in the response headers bypasses fastly as per their documentation: https://docs.fastly.com/en/guides/cache-control-tutorial#do-not-cache

Comment: I think you can use the https://www.drupal.org/project/http_response_headers module to change the header.

Comment: Drupal doesn't respond with this header for all pages, only for logged-in users. You can specify different headers in a controller or change the headers of the response before it is delivered, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/201297/47547

Comment: @4k4 I do not confirm. I've tested a dozen of Drupal 7 and 8 sites via `curl -I` on their frontpage. Doing that way means that the request/response doesn't involve a logged in user.

Comment: I get via curl `Cache-Control: max-age=x, public`, where x is the configured max-age.

Comment: Have you tried the D7/D8 test on the same server? As there's lots of reasons for different headers include your servers configuration. E.g. I can see a hosting provider I use adds this tag by default

Comment: @Leigh: Yes, I'm testing directory on Apache without anything that could alter headers in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by symfony. `private` is added via `vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ResponseHeaderBag.php` and as far as I understand it's not possible to not have it when `system.performance:cache.page.max_age` is set to 0:

```php
protected function computeCacheControlValue() {
  // ...
  if (!isset($this->cacheControl['s-maxage'])) {
    return $header.', private';
  }
```

Since I don't want to hack symfony, I can remove `private` via apache mod_header:

```
Header edit Cache-Control "(, )?private" ""
```

Comment: As commented below the question these defaults are only applied if the controller or a response event subscriber doesn't set cache headers.

Comment: My question regards why this has changed from D7 to D8 and how I can remove it.

Comment: My comment is because you've said it's not possible, but it's the opposite, you have full control if you want.

Comment: @4k4: I'm not following you. I don't want to hack symfony to change this behavior. Nor do I want to set max_age to more than 0 because that would break my site.

Comment: Symfony should allow you to return any sensible cache control header. I understand that you don't want max_age >0, but you could set a s-maxage if you want the CDN to store the response.